# Функция принимает массив, если длина массива больше нуля то возвращает true, и наоборот

Tags: javascript

```
function printResult(arr) {
  arr.length < 0 ? true : false
  return
}
const calcNumber = [5, 5]

console.log(printResult(calcNumber))
```

Да, это не так, но как будет правильно?

Comment: "если длина массива больше нуля то возвращает true" ........... "arr.length < 0 ? true"  ---- wtf?

Comment: да не то конешн, помоги что тут происходить )

Comment: ну вы изучите основы языка, прочитав книгу и сами напишите

Comment: function getLength(arr) {
  return arr.length > 0
} спасибо за совет я тут решил типа

Comment: .вот и отлично!

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то:

```js
const isArrayNotEmpty = arr => !!arr.length;

const arr1 = [5, 5];
const arr2 = [];

console.log('isArrayNotEmpty(arr1)', isArrayNotEmpty(arr1));
console.log('isArrayNotEmpty(arr2)', isArrayNotEmpty(arr2));
```

Но основы языка всё же надо учить )

Comment: да да, все изучил и понял                                                                                                                     
  function getLength(arr) {
  return arr.length > 0
}